MongoDB aggregation equivalent in Realm/ App services
I have some complex aggregation pipelines I need to execute, but  my clients are using app services. Aggregation needs to be done by connecting to the data source as I understand, which executes the query in atlas (cloud). And it takes a good 2-3 seconds in my machine, to do one aggregation and get the result back.
I know that there are some aggregation operators in RQL which are not exactly as powerful as to the actual aggregation.
I want to do some grouping, counting, and count by date  fields properties (data/ dayOfMonth, dayOfYear...and so on) ...etc. Is there a way to do at least some of those through realm objects?
e.g: How am I supposed to do a simple counting by a field, like the following pipeline result, using a realm sdk/ RQL?
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$state",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }, ...
]

